# how to shift english characters but NOT any other character in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, ascii, caesar-cipher

I'm trying to shift every english character by 2, but leave any other character(such as !, *, ^, etc) just the way it is. However, my code keeps on shifting all characters, why?

Here's my code:

```
sample = 'abcdefghijklmn-op+qr!stuvwxyz'

shift = 2

result = []

for i in range(len(sample)):
    print(f'ascii code of {sample[i]} is: {ord(sample[i])}')

print('#######################################')
ascii_code = 97

for j in range(len(sample)):
    if 96 < ord(sample[i]) < 123:
        ascii_code = ord(sample[j])
        ascii_code += shift
        if ascii_code > 122:
            ascii_code = ascii_code - 25 - 1
        
        print(f'Converted value: {chr(ascii_code)}')
```

**Expected Output**

```
ascii code of a is: 97
ascii code of b is: 98
ascii code of c is: 99
ascii code of d is: 100
ascii code of e is: 101
ascii code of f is: 102
ascii code of g is: 103
ascii code of h is: 104
ascii code of i is: 105
ascii code of j is: 106
ascii code of k is: 107
ascii code of l is: 108
ascii code of m is: 109
ascii code of n is: 110
ascii code of - is: 45
ascii code of o is: 111
ascii code of p is: 112
ascii code of + is: 43
ascii code of q is: 113
ascii code of r is: 114
ascii code of ! is: 33
ascii code of s is: 115
ascii code of t is: 116
ascii code of u is: 117
ascii code of v is: 118
ascii code of w is: 119
ascii code of x is: 120
ascii code of y is: 121
ascii code of z is: 122
#######################################
Converted value: c
Converted value: d
Converted value: e
Converted value: f
Converted value: g
Converted value: h
Converted value: i
Converted value: j
Converted value: k
Converted value: l
Converted value: m
Converted value: n
Converted value: o
Converted value: p
Converted value: -
Converted value: q
Converted value: r
Converted value: +
Converted value: s
Converted value: t
Converted value: !
Converted value: u
Converted value: v
Converted value: w
Converted value: x
Converted value: y
Converted value: z
Converted value: a
Converted value: b
```

**Code Output**

```
ascii code of a is: 97
ascii code of b is: 98
ascii code of c is: 99
ascii code of d is: 100
ascii code of e is: 101
ascii code of f is: 102
ascii code of g is: 103
ascii code of h is: 104
ascii code of i is: 105
ascii code of j is: 106
ascii code of k is: 107
ascii code of l is: 108
ascii code of m is: 109
ascii code of n is: 110
ascii code of - is: 45
ascii code of o is: 111
ascii code of p is: 112
ascii code of + is: 43
ascii code of q is: 113
ascii code of r is: 114
ascii code of ! is: 33
ascii code of s is: 115
ascii code of t is: 116
ascii code of u is: 117
ascii code of v is: 118
ascii code of w is: 119
ascii code of x is: 120
ascii code of y is: 121
ascii code of z is: 122
#######################################
Converted value: c
Converted value: d
Converted value: e
Converted value: f
Converted value: g
Converted value: h
Converted value: i
Converted value: j
Converted value: k
Converted value: l
Converted value: m
Converted value: n
Converted value: o
Converted value: p
Converted value: /
Converted value: q
Converted value: r
Converted value: -
Converted value: s
Converted value: t
Converted value: #
Converted value: u
Converted value: v
Converted value: w
Converted value: x
Converted value: y
Converted value: z
Converted value: a
Converted value: b
```

How can I fix this? It's strange to me how the code shifts -, +, ! despite the conditions.

Comment: `96 < ord(sample[i]) < 123:` does not do what you think, you cannot chain operators this way.

Comment: @Quimby What am I supposed to do then? ```if ord(sample[i]) > 96 and ord(sample[i]) < 123:``` gives me the same wrong output anyway.

Comment: Why is your loop over `j` but your `if` condition over `i`?

Comment: @Mania You are also using the wrong index.

Comment: @Mortz shit :D How didn't I notice that... thanks :)

Comment: @Mortz comment is correct

Comment: another home work?

Comment: @Quimby yes, you [_can_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) chain operators this way.

Comment: For what it's worth the set of characters you're wanting to work on are known as the ASCII printable characters. They're used for more than just English, and they were not invented for English :)

Comment: @Iguananaut they want to work specifically with Latin letters, not any ASCII printable chars.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. But they're still not English letters :)

Comment: @Iguananaut yeah sorry, I'm not an expert like u after all, still in the noob phase :'))

Comment: I don't think it's even a question of being an "expert" or not--just a pet peeve of mine, sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditions should be like this:

```
sample = 'abcdefghijklmn-op+qr!stuvwxyz'

shift = 2

result = []

for i in range(len(sample)):
    print(f'ascii code of {sample[i]} is: {ord(sample[i])}')

print('#######################################')
ascii_code = 97

for j in range(len(sample)):
    ascii_code = ord(sample[j])
    if 64 < ascii_code < 91 or 96 < ascii_code < 123:
        ascii_code += shift
    if ascii_code > 122:
        ascii_code = ascii_code - 25 - 1
      
    print(f'Converted value: {chr(ascii_code)}')
```

You shouldn't increment the value of any character unless it's an English one - which is identified by being in the range of 64 to 91 (for uppercase letters), or in the range of 96 to 123 (for lowercase letters).